# Need to fetch feed items created by my friends from Firebase using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore is as follows:

I have a user collection with a friends subcollection where each document has a `userId`, and a feed collection where each document has a `createdBy` field with the same userID.

Now, If I'm an authenticated user I need to write a function that fetches all feed items from my friends. The problem is, Firebase doesn't allow me to run the query with more than 10 friends at a time.

I was doing this like so:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchFeed(
      {required List<String> friendList}) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('feed')
        .where('createdBy', whereIn: friendList)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .limit(10)
        .get();
  }
```

where friendsList is a List with my friends. Problem is, Firebase doesn't allow me to query friendList.length > 10, and if I batch them it doesn't show the posts in the right order anymore. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I already had this kind of issue, it was while mixing where() and orderBy().

I ended up by sorting the list once I receive it.

I found this also:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4398
You can try with limitToLast().

Let me know what you do and what works :)